# Serverless: Creating S3Bucket and BucketPolicy [Unresolved resource dependencies]

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I'm trying to create an `S3 Bucket` and a corresponding `Resource Policy` in the same `serverless.yml` so that both are established on the new stack formation.

However, I am running into an error on build:

```
Unresolved resource dependencies [CUSTOM-BUCKETNAME] in the Resources block of the template
```

Is there to a way to synchronously create the policy so that it waits for the bucket to be created first? I'm setting this up in the `resources` section of my yml

```
resources:
  Resources:
    Bucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: CUSTOM-BUCKETNAME
    BucketPolicy:
      Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
      Properties:
        Bucket: 
          Ref: CUSTOM-BUCKETNAME
        PolicyDocument:
          Statement:
            - Principal: 
                Service: "ses.amazonaws.com"
              Action:
                - s3:PutObject
              Effect: Allow
              Sid: "AllowSESPuts"
          Resource: 
            Fn::Join: ['', ['arn:aws:s3:::', Ref: "CUSTOM-BUCKETNAME", '/*'] ]
```

Above is a small snippet of my yml configuration.

After using DependsOn, I'm still getting the same error. Worth note, the resource dependency refers to the dynamic name (CUSTOM-BUCKETNAME) of the bucket.

```
resources:
  Resources:
    Bucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: CUSTOM-BUCKETNAME
    BucketPolicy:
      Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
      DependsOn: Bucket
      Properties:
        Bucket: 
          Ref: CUSTOM-BUCKETNAME
        PolicyDocument:
          Statement:
            - Principal: 
                Service: "ses.amazonaws.com"
              Action:
                - s3:PutObject
              Effect: Allow
              Sid: "AllowSESPuts"
          Resource: 
            Fn::Join: ['', ['arn:aws:s3:::', Ref: "CUSTOM-BUCKETNAME", '/*'] ]
```

CUSTOM-BUCKETNAME is never explicity hardcoded in the yml itself, its a dynamically generated name using template literals.

Comment: Why can't you do it both independently?

Comment: Every time we generate the `yml` it kills the existing cloudFormation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is occurring on your policy as your bucket is: `BucketName: CUSTOM-BUCKETNAME`

Not a referenced parameter. Which means your not referencing the actual resource in the policy statement when your using `Bucket: Ref: CUSTOM-BUCKETNAME`.

Instead, either change the bucket name to reference the same parameter `BucketName: Ref: CUSTOM-BUCKETNAME` or change the policy to reference the resource: `Bucket: Ref: Bucket`

Comment: This was it! Needed to pass in the functional-name of the resource, not the actual name of the bucket.

Answer (score 2):

CloudFormation `DependsOn` attribute should solve your problem.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html

Comment: i think thats definitely close to the solution! Although I wonder if there is an issue with my string interpolations thats causing it to not fully work. Would you mind taking a look at my updated?